# Windows 7 Update Failed on Multiple attempts

Tags: windows-7

I have been unsuccessful in installing *Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7*. Here are errors for windows update history log.

[image: Windows Update Failed]

I also get the following message on failed bootup.

[image]

Based on some of the online information I have tried [clean boot on windows 7](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/228#win7) followed by an attempt to install the Security Monthly Quality Rollup.

As suggest by my online research I have run the [windows update troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter). Here is the output from the windows update troubleshooter.

[image: Troubleshooter complete]

Below is the output from setupact file. There are fair amount of `CreateFileW failed` entries in the file. Not sure if this is relevant.

```
2018-05-13 08:06:22, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 09:45:38, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 11:07:48, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 13:24:34, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 14:32:25, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 20:34:18, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-13 23:51:25, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-14 07:34:19, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-14 20:55:03, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
2018-05-15 06:05:47, Info                  DPX    CreateFileW failed, FileName:\\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\a350a656b9d7be6324a86529cf4b81f0\$dpx$.tmp\job.xml, Error:0x80070002
```

Below is link to cbs.log file bottom to up.

- [CBS.log](https://pastebin.com/0nsrBSUh)
- [CBS.log Sorted by CBS_E string](https://pastebin.com/5RMQAqBD)
- [CBS.log sorted by HRESULT string](https://pastebin.com/V2ng2xDE)

I am yet to find success

**Question:** Has anyone on this forum encountered similar issues? If so some guidance on resolve this issue?

**[Edited] Resolution:** Review CBS log. Rebuilt the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network{4aa6e004-e325-11ce-bfc1-080023410318} tree structure and the config register binary variable

References:

- [Rerun failed Windows Update](https://superuser.com/questions/563277/rerun-failed-windows-update)
- [“Failed to Configure” restart loop with Windows 7 Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates)
- [Strange Windows 7 Security Monthly Quality Rollup Update failure](https://superuser.com/questions/1253315/strange-windows-7-security-monthly-quality-rollup-update-failure?rq=1)

Comment: I would run a chkdsk on the system drive.

Comment: @Moab, I did run chkdsk, it didn't find any errors, any other ideas.

Comment: Take a look at setupact.log file as suggest by @user3169 in this comment https://superuser.com/questions/1253315/strange-windows-7-security-monthly-quality-rollup-update-failure?rq=1#comment1841814_1253315

Comment: you need to analyze the CBS.log, everything else is speculation.

Comment: Try method 2 on this page...https://www.repairwin.com/fix-kb4103718-kb4103712-update-fails-to-install-windows-7/

Comment: @Moab thank you for the note, per the update I see some errors listed referencing software distribution directory. Let me try your suggestion. I also try method 2 as suggest on the link, automated. That didn't work either.

Comment: @magicandre1981 can you please provide some guidance on what to look for in the CBS.log file. Any words or phrase it might shed some light.

Comment: read it from button to top and look for ERROR after the timestamp. if you need help, share the complete log

Comment: @magicandre1981. I posted part of the cbs.log starting from the bottom.

Comment: share the complete log (via Onedrive/dropbox share link), you only posted irrelevant data.

Comment: have you uploaded the complete log?

Comment: log doesn't include anything helpful. Share the complete CBS folder with the older logs. Copy the whole folder to desktop, create a zip of the CBS folder and share the zip via OneDrive/Dropbox/GoogleDrive share link.

Comment: Take look at the post. Sort the cbs file and post a list of errors.

Comment: @magicandre1981, I updated the post.

Comment: I see no link to a zip.

Comment: @magicandre1981. Thank you for your interest. The issue was with a corrupted network binary file in the registry. As soon as it was fixed I was able to load the updates.

Comment: ok, post in an answer which file was damaged, how you found the cause and what you did to repair the file.

Comment: @magicandre1981, my colleagues in the company IT department help fix the problem. They deleted some networking entries in the registry and on reboot issue were fixed. The system didn't revert the update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is resolved and the user @MahendraGunawardena can't tell any details how the helping people fixed it so he can't write an own answer. So the best would be the close the question.

Comment: @magicandre1981, per the company IT team, they had rebuilt the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4aa6e004-e325-11ce-bfc1-080023410318}` tree structure and the `config` register binary variable. Let me know if you need anything other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some context into the CBS and CSI might help seek a solution. Therefore the following insights and suggestion might of help.

Following are some of the services that add entries to CBS log.

- CBS (Component Based Servicing) – Also known as the trusted installer
  (TRUSTEDINSTALLER.EXE), which works at the package / update level
- CSI (Component Servicing Infrastructure) – Works at the
  deployment/component level
- DMI (Driver Management and Install) – Advanced driver installation processes
- CMI (Component Management Infrastructure) – Handles the advanced installers
- SMI (Systems Management Infrastructure) – Used to manage registry settings
- Kernel Transaction Manager (KTM) – Enables clients to use the transactional
  registry and file system

The above are discuss in greater detail in [Understanding Component-Based Servicing (Understanding Component-Based Servicing)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing/). With the knowledge of the above look errors in the CBS.log

Following is a list of suggested error codes to start from:

```
0xf0805 CBS_E_INVALID_PACKAGE the update package was not a valid CSI update      
0xf0806 CBS_E_PENDING the operation could not be complete due to locked resources
0xf0807 CBS_E_NOT_INSTALLABLE the component referenced is not separately installable
0xf0808 CBS_E_IMAGE_NOT_ACCESSIBLE the image location specified could not be accessed
0xf0809 CBS_E_ARRAY_ELEMENT_MISSING attempt to get non-existent array element
0xf080A CBS_E_REESTABLISH_SESSION session object updated, must recreate session
0xf080B CBS_E_PROPERTY_NOT_AVAILABLE requested property is not supported
0xf080C CBS_E_UNKNOWN_UPDATE named update not present in package
0xf080D CBS_E_MANIFEST_INVALID_ITEM invalid attribute or element name encountered
0xf080E CBS_E_MANIFEST_VALIDATION_DUPLICATE_ATTRIBUTES multiple attributes have the same name
```

For additional information take a look at [Windows Update error code list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/938205/windows-update-error-code-list)

It would be a good idea to sort some of the errors into file and post the errors instead of the complete cbs.log file.

A variant of the following command might be of helpful.

```
findstr/c: "CBS_E_" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log>cbs_error.txt
```

In addition consider running [Checksur (System Update Readiness)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) tool that might fix some errors due to corrupted files.